# Can't install programs from terminal - error "403 forbidden"

Tags: apt, updates

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. I can't install anything, not even update the basics. For example, if I run `sudo apt install mysql-server`, the output says:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1
  403  Forbidden
E: Fail to obtain http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Err:1 http//archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1
  403  Forbidden
Err:2 http//archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-5.7 amd64 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1
  403  Forbidden
```

Any ideas or help, please!!

Comment: Try accessing one of those sites on your web browser, for example, [this one](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb). Are you using a proxy?

Comment: Well, i can acces the links without problem on a browser, and download stuff, however, terminal won't let me.

Comment: typos in the addresses (`http//` instead of `http://`)?

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too, I can do without any problem with some ISPs, but some of them still have the problem.
A VPN connection solved my problem, you can use a proxy app to ride this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: it seems that permissions were misconfigured on my session, all I had to do was to open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and change permissions with a `chmod 0766 -R *`.